# How to globally replace programming code using literal input files?

Tags: bash, python, perl

I will use HTML as an example. But it could be any programming code for any language. This comes up often enough, it would be useful to deal with the literal text code to search and replace.

This is an example.

I want to replace in thousands of .html files this:

```
<h2 class="et_tophat">
<a href="http://example.com">example.com</a>
</h2>
```

With this:

```
<div class="tophat" id="myHeader">
  <A HREF="http://newexample.com">NewExample</A>
</div>
```

How can this be done without having to hand code the backslashes and escapes. It seems like there might be a utility or parameter I'm unfamiliar with on a Linux command such as Perl, etc. to read the search example in from an input file and the replacement string from another input file, and it would process it to make this change globally in many files?

Comment: Why do you have thousands of HTML files in the first place?

Comment: Client legacy system. Does that matter? Can you answer the question?

Comment: Yes. Might be easier to regenerate them with a new template.  It not, Perl can do multi line regexps and in-line editing for text files. If xhtml I would use XSLT

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex is a hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239). Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.

Comment: If you want to write Python code to perform this substitution, see [`re.escape()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) to match on a literal string. (You might still need to do something about the multi-line side of it.)

Comment: In Perl, what you want is [`quotemeta`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) or the `\Q...\E` modifier to match a literal string as part of a regexp.

Answer (score 1):

Here is answer using a XML parser: [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/overview.php)

Given this input file:

```
<html>
  <h2 class="et_tophat">
    <a href="http://example.com">example.com</a>
  </h2>
  <h2 class="et_tophat">
    <a href="http://example.com">example2.com</a>
  </h2>
  <div>
    <h2 class="et_tophat">
      <a href="http://example.com">example.com</a>
    </h2>
  </div>
</html>
```

You can update all `h2` elements having the properties you listed using this command:

```
xmlstarlet ed -O \
   -r '//h2[@class = "et_tophat"]/a[@href = "http://example.com" and text()="example.com"]/..' -v 'TO_BE_CHANGED' \
   -u '//TO_BE_CHANGED/@class' -v 'tophat' \
   -u '//TO_BE_CHANGED/a/@href' -v 'http://newexample.com' \
   -u '//TO_BE_CHANGED/a' -v 'NewExample' \
   -r '//TO_BE_CHANGED' -v 'div' file
```

that results in having this output:

```
<html>
  <div class="tophat">
    <a href="http://newexample.com">NewExample</a>
  </div>
  <h2 class="et_tophat">
    <a href="http://example.com">example2.com</a>
  </h2>
  <div>
    <div class="tophat">
      <a href="http://newexample.com">NewExample</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

Some explanation of the command:

The idea is to replace an element with another recursively in the xpath.
So every time the right element is located (first `-r` and `-v` options), its name is changed to a dummy name `TO_BE_CHANGED`.

Next the element and attributes inside are changed to the correct names (option `-u` and `-v`).

The last changed done is to rename the dummy name with the real one you want, e.g. a `<div>`.

Comment: Can this be used for HTML files which are not valid HTML?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen No, xmlstarlet expect valid XML (or HTML)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd use Vim for this task. As a text editor, the workflow involving saving files in place is quite natural for it. Matching multi-line strings is also fairly easy to do. And Vim also has multiple "flavors" of regular expressions, which make it easy to escape a fixed string to turn it into a pattern for matching.

I'll describe how I'd go about accomplishing this operation step-by-step.

First I'd capture the two strings (pattern and replacement) into two registers, that way I'll be able to operate into them with expressions.

Paste the two into a document. Then start linear visual mode with `V`, select the pattern one (the one with example.com) and yank it into the "a" register using `"ay`.

Then start linear visual mode with `V`, select the replacement one (the one with newexample.com) and yank it into register "b" using `"by`.

Alright, now we need to turn the "a" register into a pattern for matching. We'll use ["very nomagic"](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5CV) regexps, which can be selected by `\V`, since then we only need to escape backslash itself and the match separator, which is a forward slash. We'll use `escape(@a,'\/')` to escape those.

We also need to replace the literal newlines with [literal `\n` strings](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Cn), which is the sequence that will match newlines. We can do this replacement with `substitute()`, matching the actual newlines with `\n` and replacing them with `\\n` (backslash needs escaping in the replacement.)

Finally, we can anchor the pattern to start at the beginning of a line, using `\^` (needs the backslash when using "very nomagic" mode.)

Putting it all together, our pattern is:

```
'\V\^'.substitute(escape(@a,'\/'),'\n','\\n','g')
```

(I know this looks hard. But once you get the practice with it, it becomes easier. Using `'incsearch'` and `'hlsearch'` also helps a lot while developing these patterns, as you can visually see what you're selecting.)

For the replacement side, all we need is the value of register "b". We can use [`\=`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#sub-replace-expression) to enter an expression on the replacement side, and `@b` is the value of register "b". So our replacement is simply:

```
'\=@b'
```

Now we can assemble the `:s/.../.../` command. We'll use [`%`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#%3A%25) as the range (find pattern anywhere in the file) and the [`/e`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3As_e) modifier, so it ignores failures when the pattern is not found. Putting it all together:

```
'%s/\V\^'.substitute(escape(@a,'\/'),'\n','\\n','g').'/\=@b/e'
```

This is still a string, so at the next step is to run it with [`:execute`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#%3Aexecute), which executes a string as a Vim command (an Ex command, to be more precise.) Also, at this step, we'll run [`:update`](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#%3Aupdate), to save the file (like `:w`) if it was modified. This will allow us to run this in a bulk command and move on to the next file. In Vim, we use [`|`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#%3Abar) as a command separator. So far:

```
:execute '%s/\V\^'.substitute(escape(@a,'\/'),'\n','\\n','g').'/\=@b/e'|update
```

(Sidebar: This part here could be abstracted into a Vim function, Search & Replace with fixed strings. It's reusable and useful on its own. I'll not take the detour, since this post is already pretty long, I'll work with the longer command lines instead, since that works quite OK in Vim as well.)

The command above can be applied to a single file and it will apply the modification, so the next step is to apply this to the thousands of HTML files.

If we plan to do this on *every* HTML file in our tree (assuming a majority or very large part of them will include the searched pattern) we can use [`:args`](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#%3Aargs_f) and `:argdo` to perform the bulk operation. We start with:

```
:args **/*.html
```

This builds a list of all files with the `html` extension under the current directory, recursing into all subdirectories.

Then, we can use [`:argdo`](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#%3Aargdo) to apply our substitute command to each and every one of them:

```
:argdo execute '%s/\V\^'.substitute(escape(@a,'\/'),'\n','\\n','g').'/\=@b/e'|update
```

Note that the `/e` and the `|update` are pretty important in this step, since we want to save changes before moving to the next file and we don't want Vim to complain about match not found if it's not found in some of the files.

Perhaps acting on *every* `*.html` file is too much and we don't have a good path expression to narrow it down. In that case, maybe we can use [`:vimgrep`](https://vimhelp.org/quickfix.txt.html#%3Avimgrep) instead (with `:vimgrep /example\.com/ **/*.html` perhaps?) or `:grep` or a plug-in such as `ack.vim`, in which case we'll get the results in the "error list" and we can use [`:cfdo`](https://vimhelp.org/quickfix.txt.html#%3Acfdo) to bulk modify them.

One great side of using Vim for this task is that it's pretty flexible. It's possible to iterate quickly and change requirements on-the-fly. You have a lot of visual feedback (it's a text editor after all!), so in that sense it's a much more interactive approach than writing a Perl or Python script to perform this substitution.

The downside is probably the complexity. These commands get quite complicated pretty quickly. If you know Vim inside out, this becomes easier, but it's a pretty steep learning curve. If anything, I hope this post at least inspires you to learn a bit more about Vim to use it to solve this kind of bulk modification, a task where it shines.